Remove chroot outright
So chroot needs to go as after days of ... "research" it doesn't properly support listing an index unless you do some crazy long command and the program has to be running to even be listed. If you can't do something competently then don't do it.
So, with maybe a comprehension level of 2 out of 10 on the Linux terminal I've confirmed my distro has chroot and rpm. Unfortunately after figuring out how to filter installed packages (rpm -qa '*chroot*') it turns out that chroot is not installed as a package. I went with this route because of a well-asked question though likely a different Linux setup which someone asked here: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1511346
I don't know if it's a native command or something else. I fully comprehend and appreciate locking access down for various processes but a secure system that doesn't function is worthless.
How do I safely remove chroot from Linux without causing damage to the file system?

On Fedora, chroot is part of the coreutils package.

Please take a step back and start from the beginning. Edit your question and explain what the issue is. You mention that chroot doesn't "support listing an index". What index? What listing? If you don't want to be in a chroot environment, just don't run chroot, why would you want to actually uninstall such a basic package? And what is your distro anyway? We need to understand the issue before we can help.

The linked question is about BIND in a chroot. Along with those two articles, you might want to also see: Why running named(bind) in chroot is so important for security? Or maybe it is not? and Running BIND in a chrooted environment.

Possible precursor question: Extending chroot jail or removing it, which starts "I discovered that on a new server that PHP is in "chroot jail"." and finally asks, "how do I properly dismantle the "chroot jail""

John, the question you are asking here is completely irrelevant to your question about the PHP chroot jail. I would recommend you delete this one and concentrate on the one you originally asked - bearing in mind you asked it only 12 hours ago and some people may not have even woken up yet to read it

After a few seconds with a search engine I found multiple tutorials and examples on how to use chroot. What "research" did you do that took days of effort to understand what chroot is used for, what limits it places on an environment, and how to modify the environment?

The correct answer is rarely the popular answer though perhaps this might have a positive effect for those capable of "getting it" and who aren't vulnerable to completely depending on the lazy social-proof technique by looking at the answer score. The problem with chroot is it was not properly developed. Any functionality must have support for five core functions:

Index: displaying a list of all instances.
Create: if you can't create something you can't use it.
Edit: if you can't modify it then that makes the create process pointlessly convoluted.
Search: if you can't find one or multiple instances when there could be hundreds then that is too complicated.
Delete: if you can't remove something then that creates more problems.

The chroot command only supports the create functionality - it does not support anything else! Apparently this dates back to the late 1990s?! So literally thousands of other developers could have fixed this function over the past two decades and change - and didn't. No - I don't know about any like-functions, destroying half a week of my time is wildly irresponsible for whoever decided it was a good or desirable idea to use this function which isn't even half built!
I fully comprehend the notion of why it was created but the problem is the missing edit functionality, if at least that had been built at all and properly should have extended the chroot jail to include files in the regular file system - not copies! As a developer it is my responsibility to track when things need to be updated. If something I'm referencing is a copy then the data I'm referencing is wrong! Properly extended functionality would also include permissions: read, write and execute and I only need to read these files. How many developers could produce this functionality in a couple of days if even that?!
So once I'm able to afford to pay a Linux developer properly I'll have them create an actual proper function that is easily far superior. A good idea is only effectively good if the execution is good too!
Breaking Chroot Jail (without having to remove it outright)

I logged in to the Linux root user using PuTTY / SSH.
I used the command find / -name '*chroot*' to find instances in the file system.
I cleared excessive redundant / useless instances in Notepad++.
I noticed many instances in directory names for cagefs.
I eventually went in to WHM and found that there was a plugin for CageFS.
I saw the Linux user PHP uses (shell_exec('whoami')) and removed them.
After the commit got logged out on my own system (good sign).
Got in to my own control panel and saw that the relevant shell_exec() commands were now working.

Unfortunately I don't know the syntax for the problem so for someone who does not have a similar setup I apologize as it's clear most people are going to fight against you. In general the chroot jail is a good idea albeit executed as badly as it gets while still being blindly accepted. If you are not tracking something important like software versions via server variables to keep the software updated then no, there is likely no reason to need to break the chroot jail however you can not be free unless you're also responsible.

I think you fundamentally misunderstand how linux works and what chroot is for. chroot doesn't need fixing, it needs replacing, and it was replaced years ago with full containers. It's basically vestigial in linux, but it is still useful for its original intended purpose. You have a low score because your fundamentals are wrong and you've missed the point.  As asked, your question makes little sense, and your answer is barely relevant to the question.

The information in your previous question included a reference to /usr/share/cagefs-skeleton.
That suggests the thing you're having trouble with might not be just a normal chroot, but a cagefs, which is a feature of CloudLinux and apparently ties into various hosting control panels such as cPanel, Plesk and others.
It seems you don't so much want to remove the chroot command (which is a part of the coreutils package, by the way), as remove the chroot setup that is restricting your PHP web scripts. If so, it seems to me that in that case, CloudLinux might be a wrong choice of distribution for the kind of application you're trying to make.
The "Cloud way" of updating your operating system would be:

go to your hosting administration panel
spin up a new VM with the OS version of your choice from templates offered by your hoster
re-deploy your application on it using your automation of choice
destroy the old version of the cloud VM

CloudLinux appears to be tailored specifically for that kind of operating paradigm. I don't know how exactly you want to work with your application, but from your questions, it seems to me the "cloud way" isn't really it.
Ripping cagefs out of CloudLinux would probably more work than re-deploying your application on a different distribution that is more suitable to the way you want to operate.

I'm just seeing this now though you brought up cagefs and clearly are trying to help. I did resolve it on my own though I still want to throw a +1 your way for your positive intentions. I posted my own answer with the specifics. Any way, thank you @telcoM.

$ type chroot
chroot is /usr/sbin/chroot
$ rpm -qf /usr/sbin/chroot
coreutils-8.30-15.el8.x86_64

I find it highly unlikely that coreutils is not installed on your system. And you really, really don't want to remove coreutils from any GNU/Linux system.
The rpm -qa command lists packages, not their contents.  Not every file has its own package and most packages contain many files.
The existence of a binary has little to do with processes on the system.  The ps command does not make an index, and you almost certainly will never see chroot running, and it won't start all by itself.
Removing unused services is a good idea, but removing things you don't understand, service or binary, is not a good idea at all.
There is no point in removing chroot, it won't make your system more secure.

I'd argue that removing chroot makes the system less secure by removing one way to decrease attack surface. It also might break programs, including vital system software such as package managers.

This answer mentions GNU/Linux, but the OP's distro might, for example, use musl instead of glibc and Busybox instead of coreutils. In the case of Busybox, the symlink could be removed, but chroot can always be started by issuing the busybox chroot command. The only way to completely remove chroot command would be to recompile Busybox from source.

@Vilinkameni, "The only way to completely remove chroot command would be to recompile Busybox from source" - but if you can do that you can certainly write your own main() { chroot(argv[1]); execl(argv[2],(char *)NULL } } or whatever

@ChrisDavies Yes, the OP's "noop chroot" would likely involve patching Busybox's chroot instead of turning it off with configure. Still, compilation and installation from source would be required. And abuild would likely wreak havoc with such a replacement.

@user10489 Thank you, the is command is interesting and I'll update my Linux terminal notes. I was able to disable chroot for the Linux user that PHP uses without causing damage (I posted an answer with the details). +1 for your insight, thank you.

"the is command is interesting" - there is no is command. The line above that was the command (i.e. type chroot) and the output from that command was chroot is /usr/sbin/chroot
